# Shoulder Blade Problem

Tags: shoulder-cuff

I have pain around my right shoulder blade and It is not going away. I went to a doctor, he gave me medicine and it did not work. Whenever I cough I feel pain around the blade and there's also pain in my right pec. The shoulder blade pain consistent but the pec pain only occurs whenever I cough but only for the time I am coughing. Plz somebody give me a fix.

Comment: Ask on health stack exhange there you can find specialized doctors and students.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to diagnose issues like this over the internet. Having said that, doctors are notoriously bad at helping with any form of muscular issue. You're much better off going to see a physiotherapist or even a sports masseur.

Comment: @Esrien - No. Health SE does not allow "diagnose me" or "Fix my X" questions any more than fitness does. Anything like this needs to be looked at by medical professionals in person.